# What does width:*; do in CSS?

Tags: css

I have been told that I can use * to make a width fill out the remaining space, ex. with several `div`s within another `div`.

It works when I write it in the code as well, but... I need a relevant source before I am allowed to use it in my semester project, can anyone help me out?

```
div {
    width:*;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not valid to use `*`. See the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width).

You can define `width` as an absolute value (like in pixels), percentage, `auto` or `inherit`.

Extract from the spec:

```
Values have the following meanings:

<length> - Specifies the width of the content area using a length unit.
<percentage> - Specifies a percentage width. (...)
auto - The width depends on the values of other properties. See the sections below.

Negative values for 'width' are illegal.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `*` on rules, when you're trying to do `width:*;`

You can use it in selectors though. When used on a selector it means "anything". For example, the following targets anything that has an `<li>` as an ancestor.

```
li * { 
    /* */ 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The asterisk (*) character is a wildcard selector that will apply a set of styles to every element on the page. For example:

```
*
{
    color:red;
}
```

The above will set the colour of the text of all elements on the page to "red".

Usually it is not a good idea to use it because it can take a while for the browser to apply this selector to every element on the page, especially if the page contain lots of elements.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking. See kamituel's response